# Multipile forms with input and submit button with the same action with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a Form with Input and a submit button (Javascript),
I duplicated the form 3 times in order to create 3 different options, although these options use the same Javascript for input errors and for submission,
this resulted in giving me an error if i do not enter value on the first form on the page, while I am trying to use the second or third form.

the JS file:

```
jQuery(function($){
$('form#unlock').on('submit', function (e){
    if($('#the_imei').val().length == 15){
        if($('#the_imei').val().indexOf('9900') === 0){
         alert('לפי המספר IMEI, ברשותכם מכשיר CDMA, אנא ראו מידע נוסף בעמוד פתיחת מכשירי CDMA');
         window.location = 'http://www.unlocker.co.il/sim-unlock-cdma-mobile-device';
         e.preventDefault();
             }
        return;
    }

    alert('אנא מלאו מספר IMEI בעל 15 ספרות');
    e.preventDefault();
}); 
})
```

And the page URL is: http://www.unlocker.co.il/shop/sim-unlock-htc-mobile-device/

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that came to mind is if you are simply duplicating the form by copy and pasting the form code, is that you are duplicating any id's.  **ID's need to be unique.**  If you have more than one id with the same name, then Javascript will only recognize the first one in the page.

**Edit:**

To be more specific for your first form... (notice the input change of `id` to `class`)

```
<form id="unlock1" class="cart" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="unlock">
        <input class="the_imei" style="width: 80%; border-radius: 15px;" name="the_imei" type="text" value="" placeholder="מספר סידורי IMEI של המכשיר (חייג #06#*)"><br>
        <input class="add-to-cart" name="add-to-cart" type="hidden" value="39"><br>
        <button class="unlockButton" type="submit" value="submit">פתח לכל הרשתות בישראל </button>
</form>
```

Then for your script...

```
    jQuery(function($){
    $('form#unlock1').on('submit', function (e){
        if($('form#unlock1 > input.the_imei').val().length == 15){
            if($(this).val().indexOf('9900') === 0){
             alert('לפי המספר IMEI, ברשותכם מכשיר CDMA, אנא ראו מידע נוסף בעמוד פתיחת מכשירי CDMA');
             window.location = 'http://www.unlocker.co.il/sim-unlock-cdma-mobile-device';
             e.preventDefault();
                 }
            return;
        }

    alert('אנא מלאו מספר IMEI בעל 15 ספרות');
    e.preventDefault();
    }); 
   })
```

Comment: I did exactly that now, I changed each form ID, added 1,2,3 to them, and duplicated the JS file, each for an ID. And this basically solved the above problem,although it added a different problem with the Submit function, hitting the Submit button on any of the forms, causes all to functions\forms to react. Now I need a solution on how to make **only** the form that it's button was pressed to react and the rest to be disabled while only the 1 that is filled reacts.

Comment: Same problem still exists. You still have some duplicate id's on the page. e.g. `#the_imei`  is the same in each form. I don't know if that is what is causing the problem you are describing.  What do you mean wheb you say they they "react?"  I typed some numbers into one and I just get a popup dialogue, I don't see the other forms doing anything. Submitting something in the top form is currently returning an error.

Comment: I edited my answer above with the HTML, and jQuery for one form.  Use it as a guide and it should help you get the other forms working as well.

Comment: I was messing around with the first form, so i probably left it with an error so you need to test the second and third to get what the problems i described. by "React" i meant that when you click the submit button, on any of those forms, it "Submits" all 3 of them, instead of the specific one you are trying to submit. By the way, the forms are for IMEI unlocks for phones, so it will error if you put less than 15digits. I am gonna try your new script now, thanks so much

Comment: It works great, I thank you very much good sir, for your time and help.

Comment: Will you mark the answer as excepted then please? Thanks.

Comment: Weird thing, i changed nothing on the script itself, but now the 15 digits error appears, and the 9900 error doesn't, it just submits it without erroring

Comment: Really this is a new question/problem, and my answer was a solution to your first problem. So you really should not "un-except" the answer. People who look at the question are going to point out the same things as I did, without perhaps studying your actual code. Even If I put a new answer for this new problem, it won't be an answer to the original question, so I might get voted down by others. So please reaccept the answer, and simply ask a new question. And I or another will try to help.  In the new question you can add a link to this one if you want people to see the connection

Comment: Ok Skribe, I thought if i posted a new question i'd be like spamming.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647629/form-submit-with-2-different-errors-depending-on-input-value-1-is-not-working

i posted, thanks again :)