# Form submit with 2 different errors depending on input value - 1 is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I posted a question on how to make 2 errors work here: [Multipile forms with input and submit button with the same action with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522216/multipile-forms-with-input-and-submit-button-with-the-same-action-with-javascrip/28522255?noredirect=1#comment45592529_28522255)

I needed 2 errors, 1 error if the input if less than 15 digits, the second error is if the input begins with 9900 (if it does, there is an error and then it redirects to a different page).
It worked for a while, although suddenly it stopped giving the second error (if input starts with 9900), the page is: http://www.unlocker.co.il/shop/sim-unlock-htc-mobile-device/

Each form has it's own id: unlock1, unlock2, unlock3 etc.
the JS files include:

```
    jQuery(function($){
$('form#unlock1').on('submit', function (e){
    if($('form#unlock1 > input.the_imei').val().length == 15){
        if($(this).val().indexOf('9900') === 0){
         alert('לפי המספר IMEI, ברשותכם מכשיר CDMA, אנא ראו מידע נוסף בעמוד פתיחת מכשירי CDMA');
         window.location = 'http://www.unlocker.co.il/sim-unlock-cdma-mobile-device';
         e.preventDefault();
             }
        return;
    }

alert('אנא מלאו מספר IMEI בעל 15 ספרות');
e.preventDefault();
});   
})
```

and the Forms are:

```
<form id="unlock1" class="cart" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="unlock"> <input class="the_imei" style="width: 80%; border-radius: 15px;" name="the_imei" type="text" value="" placeholder="מספר סידורי IMEI של המכשיר (חייג #06#*)" /> <input class="add-to-cart" name="add-to-cart" type="hidden" value="39" /> <button class="unlockButton" type="submit" value="submit">פתח לכל הרשתות בישראל </button> </form>
```

Each form has a different id (example Unlock1) and on it's own JS file the id like listed in 2 places.

I can't figure out why the "minimum 15 digits" error works, but the "if input begins with 9900" error does not work anymore.

Thanks!

Comment: You are wanting this line `if($(this).val().indexOf('9900') === 0)` to return the alert if someone inputs something like 990012345678910 right?

Comment: exactly. If someone enters 15 digits but the first 4 digits are 9900, this should return the CDMA alert and redirect the page

Comment: I put it in a test box, and it does work for me. I get the first alert if there is not 15digits, and the second alert if the 15digits start with 9900

Comment: Really?,i check on both IE and on Chrome, it just add to cart when i put a number that begins with 9900. What browser are you using?
Maybe you have my site caches on your browser as it was before something suddenly changed?

Comment: Yes. I am using Chrome.  I put the code in a plain page. Set up the simple form, and run it in my browser and it works like expected.

Comment: Sorry it took long to respond... Here is a demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Byxabb

Comment: But it wouldn't work with more than 1 form on the page, because "the_imei" is the name of all of them.

A fellow helped me with this,
the answer is:

if(document.getElementsByName('the_imei')[0].value.indexOf('9900') == 0){

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do this. Try to avoid using too many nested if statments. Instead create the escape clauses with return statements when the user enters the incorrect value first.

```
$('form#unlock1').on('submit', function(){
  var $el = $('form#unlock1 > input.the_imei');

  if($el.val().length<15){
    //Not enough characters
    return false;
  }

  if($el.val().substring(0,4)=='9900') {
    //Value begins with 9900
    return false;
  }

  //User has entered a correct imei
});
```